# Split json alike string by regex expression

Tags: c#, regex, arrays

I would like to split the string below by using regex expression

```
Country:Subdivision, Level1:{Level2a:{Level3a, Level3b}, Level2b}
```

into form of

```
Country
   Subdivision
Level1
   Level2a
      Level3a
      Level3b
   Level2b
```

I knew there will be a recursive function to split to string into the above form.

I'm using .net, and want to split to string into a class

```
public class ListHierarchy
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ListHierarchy ParentListHierarchy { get; set; }
}
```

The concept as below (Output):

```
var list1 = new ListHierarchy() { Name = "Country" };
var list2 = new ListHierarchy() { Name = "Subdivision", ParentListHierarchy = list1 };
var list3 = new ListHierarchy() { Name = "Level1" };
var list4 = new ListHierarchy() { Name = "Level2a", ParentListHierarchy = list3 };
var list5 = new ListHierarchy() { Name = "Level2b", ParentListHierarchy = list3 };
var list6 = new ListHierarchy() { Name = "Level3a", ParentListHierarchy = list4 };
var list7 = new ListHierarchy() { Name = "Level3b", ParentListHierarchy = list4 };
```

Guys, I have to solution already, but still need to fine tune on the regex

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> SplitToDictionary(string input, string regexString)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(regexString);
    return regex.Matches(input).Cast<Match>().ToDictionary(x => x.Groups[1].Value.Trim(), x => x.Groups[2].Value.Trim());
}

string input = "Country:Subdivision, Level1:{Level2a:{Level3a:Level4a, Level3b}, Level2b}";

 var listHierarchy = new List<ListHierarchy>();
 Dictionary<string, string> listParent = SplitToDictionary(input, @"([\w\s]+):(([\w\s]+)|([\w\s\,\{\}\:]+))");
```

but, i getting

```
{Level2a:{Level3a, Level3b}, Level2b}
```

rather than

```
Level2a:{Level3a, Level3b}, Level2b
```

Comment: Trust me, you don't want to use a regex for this. You want a JSON parser. I'm pretty sure the language you're using (which you didn't specify) already has one.

Comment: Actually, since this isn't valid JSON, you don't want a JSON parser, but you'll need a [recursive descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) nonetheless.

Comment: I creating a string to store my dynamic hierarchy list and json format is chosen for my string design. it is not a json but json alike string.

Comment: If you really want to use regular expressions to parse nested braces check out this one with some options - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns

Answer (score 0):

I love regular expressions, but for this problem they are just not the right tool.

[Irony](http://irony.codeplex.com/) is an awesome and very easy to use library that will let you write a parser for your json-like thing.

It's free, open source, and the examples include a json parser that you can adapt to your needs.

Answer (score -2):

you can use this regex

```
([^\s,:{}])+
```

This would get you the Country Subdivision Level1 Level2a Level3a Level3b Level2b.
you would have to put it into an array and then push it out according to your style.

**EDIT**

This would actively destroy the JSON hierarchy therefore is not recommended to be used for this question/situation. This would only return strings that can be stored in an array.

Comment: -1: Aside from the fact that it's not going to work, how should he be able to guess where to indent/outdent?

Comment: he was asking for the regex of getting the strings, so that is what i would suggest. i did not say how he is going to do the indent/outdent for the reason that i don't know what language he is going to use. Did you even read the part where i said how the OP styles it is up to him? so why the -1?

Comment: By using a regex, you're actively *destroying* the information he needs for indenting/outdenting.

Comment: for the indent its means child of the parent

Comment: he could use the match and split function together (if javascript) something like that to make it into an array an the style it accordingly. so how am i actively destroying the information? unless i am missing something here.

Comment: Your regex isn't even doing what you say it does. If it was `([^\s,:{}]+)` you'd get a flattened array of all non-whitespace, non-punctuation words in the original string, with all the information about their hierarchical positions *removed*.

Comment: if it was the hierarchy position, then yes, you are right there, this would destroy that information. i only said this regex would get you the string, i did not say it would be a hierarchical type like JSON. so you could at least ask before you gave a -1.

Comment: my answer is wrong, so i guess the -2 is okay. =) updated it to reflect the wrong answer